# How can I vectorize an iteration over a pandas that iterate over a list?

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on a big dataset about 200k rows, I need to create a new column whit an element of a list if the values pass two conditions, the dataset I use looks like this:

```
timestamp                                    sell2    close                
1597133400                            [11959, 11971]  11760.0
1597133700                            [11959, 11971]  11773.5
1597134000                       [12339.6, 12457.12]  11752.0
1597134300                     [12331.725, 12449.17]  11744.5
1597134600                       [12320.7, 12438.04]  11734.0
1597134900                     [12315.975, 12433.27]  11729.5
1597135200                            [11923, 11935]  11732.0
1597135500                            [11923, 11935]  11745.5
1597135800                      [12336.45, 12453.94]  11749.0
1597136100                            [11923, 11935]  11724.0
1597136400                     [12354.825, 12472.49]  11766.5
1597136700  [12354.300000000001, 12471.960000000001]  11766.0
1597137000                      [12351.15, 12468.78]  11763.0
1597137300                       [12362.7, 12480.44]  11774.0
1597137600            [12361.65, 12479.380000000001]  11773.0
1597137900                      [12351.15, 12468.78]  11763.0
1597138200            [12343.800000000001, 12461.36]  11756.0
1597138500                     [12349.575, 12467.19]  11761.5
1597138800           [12329.625, 12447.050000000001]  11742.5
1597139100                     [12317.025, 12434.33]  11730.5
1597139400           [12313.875, 12431.150000000001]  11727.5
1597139700                       [12299.7, 12416.84]  11714.0
1597140000           [12277.125, 12394.050000000001]  11692.5
1597140300           [12291.825, 12408.890000000001]  11706.5
```

This is the code that I'm using, first it looks over all the pandas and then over a list on the column sell2

```
price_pool_short =[]
index = data4.index
for i in range(0,len(index)):
    y = [x for x in data4.sell2[data4.index==index[i]]][0]
    close = data4.close[index[i]]
    best_price = 0.007
    for j in range(len(y)):
        if (y[j]>close) and (1-(close/y[j])>best_price):
            pps = y[j]
            break
        else: 
            pps = close*1.05
    price_pool_short.append(pps)
```

and here is the desired output:

```
[11959, 11959, 12339.6, 12331.725, 12320.7,12315.975,11923,
 11923,12336.45,11923,12354.825,12354.300000000001,12351.15,12362.7,
 12361.65,12351.15,12343.800000000001,12349.575,12329.625,12317.025,
 12313.875,12299.7,12277.125,12291.825,12294.45,12297.6]
```

I am trying to make it in a vectorized way but I am having a hard time on this, I tried something like:

```
y = [x for x in data4.sell2][0]
close = data4.close.to_numpy()
best_price = 0.007
price_pool_short = np.where((y[j]>close) and (1-(close/y[j])>best_price),y[j],close*1.05)
price_pool_short
```

but it dosen't work. How can I make it in a way that consumes less time?

im adding an example of data where we can see what should happend

```
                                 sell    close
timestamp                                     
1597134300  [[[12331.725, 12449.17]]]  11744.5
1597134600    [[[12320.7, 12438.04]]]  11734.0
1597134900  [[[12315.975, 12433.27]]]  11729.5
1597135200         [[[11923, 11935]]]  11732.0
1597135500         [[[11923, 11935]]]  11745.5
1597135800   [[[12336.45, 12453.94]]]  11749.0
```

the output:

```
[12331.725, 12320.7, 12315.975, 11923, 11923, 12336.45]
```

here we have that the row 0,1,2 are on the else case(close*1.05) then the 3 and the 4 works on the if sentence, the last one agin is close*1.05

Comment: could you explain your 2 conditions in words for clarity?

Comment: for shure! the point is that i need to compare the  values of y one by one if that value is higher than the close value in the row and if the 1 less the ratio of the close and the y is higher  than  the percentage best_price, if it get a value that fill the condition then pps should be that value, if not then checks on the next, but if it does not get any result the pps is changed by the close*1.05, hope this helps! any other thing im will be here

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, explode your `sell2` column:

```
df1 = df.explode('sell2')
msk = (df1['sell2'] > df1['close']) & (1-(df1['close'] / df1['sell2']) > best_price)
price_pool_short = df1[msk].groupby(level=0)['sell2'].first().tolist()
```

Output:

```
>>> price_pool_short
[11959,
 11959,
 12339.6,
 12331.725,
 12320.7,
 12315.975,
 11923,
 11923,
 12336.45,
 11923,
 12354.825,
 12354.300000000001,
 12351.15,
 12362.7,
 12361.65,
 12351.15,
 12343.800000000001,
 12349.575,
 12329.625,
 12317.025,
 12313.875,
 12299.7,
 12277.125,
 12291.825]
```

Comment: My answer doesn't give the right result because I don't understand the logic but what you need is to explode the `sell2` column.

Comment: I'm getting the same numbers, so idk if it's a logic misunderstanding~

Comment: i think i put 2 more inputs so the last output match until the last two , thanks a lot i think this works!

Comment: @mimus. You have to add something like: `df1['sell2'].mask(~msk, other=df1['close']*1.05)`

Comment: ooooooh! thats what you saying, let me think

Comment: i dont understand the use of the  .mask(~msk, other=df1['close']*1.05), the point is that sometimes there are sell2 lists that has no values that match the condition, like having a little sell but not so little vs the close, do you think a np.where would works here?

Comment: Can you provide a shortest example where conditions are not satisfied please.

Comment: for shure! let me search

Comment: done man! i added an examplo whit the outputs

Comment: Why do you have a list of list of list now? `[[[...]]]` And all of your values in `sell` are higher than `best_price`.

Comment: its about liquidations on btc, some times the price is higher than the las close, but not too much so we need to know if we have two liquidations one next to the other or just the first but last for more than 1 candle, i have list of list cause i can have ranges like [[[1,2,3,4],[6,7,8]]], if i have not 5 thats cause the price we use here jumps from 4 to 6

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244706/discussion-between-mimus-and-corralien).